# Socket.io only emits on server restart in nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io in nodejs for chat system, and I am able to send the message on server in socket.js file in nodejs. But when I emit that message to other users from socket in nodejs. Then this message is not receiving on the client side.

Here is my nodejs code:

```
var users = [];
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    pingInterval: 5000,
    pingTimeout: 5000
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected: ",  socket.id);
    socket.on("user_connected", function (id) {
        users[id] = socket.id;
        io.emit("user_connected", id);
    });
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        var socketId = users[msg.friendId];
        socket.to(socketId).emit('new_message', msg);
        let chat = new ChatData({
            user: msg.userId,
            friend: msg.friendId,
            message: msg.message
        });
        chat.save().then(() => {
            console.log('message saved');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error is ', err);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my client side code:

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000");
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit("user_connected", userId);
});

function sendMessage(message) {
  let msg = {
    userId: userId,
    friendId: friendId,
    message: message.trim()
  }
  // Send to server
  socket.emit('message', msg);
}

// Recieve messages
socket.on('new_message', (msg) => {
 console.log(msg)
});
```

Client side socket js library https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.2/socket.io.js

Comment: It seems like the main problem here is the part with `users[id] = socket.id;`. Initially, your array is empty and thus, no `id`s are pushed to the array. Instead you should first check if the `id` already exists in the array, and if not, push it to the array. Something like `!users.includes(id) ? users.push(socket.id) : null`

Comment: I have also done this, but it is also not working. Can you please provide me the actual code for pushing socked id with the specific user id. So that, I can map which user has which socket id.

Comment: Oh so your `userId` is different from the `socket.id`? If this is the case, you could either use a `Map` or a JSON Object where your keys are the `userId` and the values are the actual `socket.id`s.